# Critical tools that every Java Developer should have in his toolbelt?

Tags: java, development-environment, tooling

I was trying to compile a list of tools that a good Java Developer should be know of, and keep in his Developer Tool Belt

I can think of a few

- Eclipse Development Environment - There are other IDEs, but you should know how Eclipse of eclipse.
- [JUnit](http://junit.org/) - Java Unit Testing Framework. Of course there are others, but...
- [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/)
- [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
- [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/) - for testing SOAP endpoints
- [jrat](http://jrat.sourceforge.net/) - Java Profiler. I don't know of other good Java profilers
- [Java Decompiler](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) - For when you just **have** to know what's in the jar file

Comment: Comment to my own post: The question is about tools, not libraries. Something that would be applicable no matter what functionality you are trying to implement.

Comment: @Timur: Then I think, Soap UI doesn't really fit in. Lots of Java developers/projects don't use SOAP.

Comment: True - But I think it is important enough for a java developers to know of its existence and to use it when service testing is required.

Comment: +1 for java decompiler. -1 for Eclipse :)

Comment: @Oscar No matter what IDE you use for JAVA development - you shouldn't be surprised if your next project requires eclipse.

Comment: By using maven I found that my IDE now needs to work around my project instead of the other way around =)

Comment: cavaj is another good decompiler.

Answer (score 3):

[*The Really Big Index: A list of all content pages in the The Java<sup>TM</sup> Tutorial*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), because you can't know *everything*.

Answer (score 2):

- Continuous integration server: CruiseControl, Hudson, etc.
- Dependency injection: Google Guice, Spring, PicoContainer
- Slf4J: Simple Logging Facade for Java
- Mockito: Mocking Library
- Not Java specific but nonetheless essential: a good distributed source control (Git or Mercurial)

Answer (score 1):

- [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) - for low level memory profiling
- [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) - for high level memory profiling
- [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) - for performance testing
- Mockito, EasyMock, PowerMock - for mocking
- FindBugs, Checkstyle, PMD - for static code analysis

Answer (score 0):

- findbugs http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/
- hudson http://hudson-ci.org/

understanding of all major version control systems like:

- perforce
- cvs
- svn
- git
- etc.

and of course the jdk!

Answer (score 0):

- Hudson, near the top of the list.
- visualVM - good enough for most profiling needs (and I've heard of a number of Java profilers, but never of jrat)
- Cobertura or Emma for code coverage

Answer (score 0):

Useful in building your apps quickly:
1. onejar - helps in quickly create executable jar with dependency and deploy for users.
2. Vaadin for building rich UI with ease.

Answer (score -2):

**Critical**

- Clean text editor ( Textmate, gVim )
- JDK ( java, javac, javap etc. )
- A webbrowser to read the javadocs

**Non-critical**

All those you mention but `s/Eclipse/IntelliJ Idea/g`